# NPM start giving error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
npm ERR! path C:\angularjs2\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open 'C:\angularjs2\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\angularjs2\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear: `ENOENT, open 'C:\angularjs2\package.json'`... `npm not being able to find a file`

Answer (score 5):

To run `npm start` you need to be in a directory where a package.json of a module that you want to start is located:

```
cd /path/to/module
npm start
```

If you don't have a package.json yet then you can create one with:

```
npm init
```

Remember that you need to define a `start` script, like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node module.js"
}
```

in package.json.

Answer (score 1):

It explains that you are not in the directory which contains the package.json file.

Most of the times you should run this command in the app directory. So, you need to cd into the directory which holds package.json then there you can run your commands like npm install, npm start etc.

So, before running these commands please check if you are in the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an error with npm start or expo (when programming in react-native) occurs when we open the vscode terminal, or another terminal not as an administrator. Just open vsc or powershell as an administartor

Answer (score 0):

If you have everything installed and "package.json" file is there in your directory then you just need to be in the directory where "package.json" file exists directly.
Be in there and open the terminal.

Mostly we are just inside some other directory where "package.json" doesn't exist directly and try to use `npm start`.
See the image below to understand and look at the commands closely.
[image: look at the terminal commands and file hierarchy]